# iOS enterprise APNs certificate expiry

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-enterprise

We have a production APNs certificate due to expire shortly for an enterprise app.

Is it just a case of creating a new production APNs certificate for our app ID and replacing the certificate that's due to expire with our push notifications provider?

Will I need to re bundle and re distribute our enterprise app or will the existing version continue to work with the new APNs certificate?

Comment: Actually you will need to add that new cert in the Push notifications configuration for your App ID on dev portal, and seems like no re-bundling would be needed.

Comment: That's right, sorry that was implied with creating the new cert. I would create a CSR upload to our developer account to then download the push certificate, install and export the p12 to the push provider. The part I was unsure on and wanted to check was regarding re bundle / distribution specifically with enterprise apps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to these links:

- https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

If a certificate expired or revoked, it doesn’t affect apps that you’ve submitted to the store, just effect ability to update them.

For APNs certificates, if it expired, you can no longer send notification to you app, it only effect the ability to your push server communicate with Apple's APNs service. Just update the APNs certificates and update your push server's push certificate, the push service will work again.